# Issuer certificate issue when init vue-cli

Tags: webpack, vue.js, certificate, vuejs2, centos7

I'm trying to initialize a new project with vue-cli (on Centos7).

But, when I run this command:

```
vue init webpack-simple myproject
```

The following error appears:

> vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack-simple: unable to get local issuer certificate

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/258

Comment: Yes I am! But I don't understand the solution proposed in the link that you indicated. What's the connection with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

- I completely uninstalled and then reinstalled nodejs on my Centos7
- I reinstalled vue-cli

Then I tried:

```
vue init webpack-simple myproject
```

And it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit lat, but can help others in the future. This fixed mine (I'm in MacOsX) :

```
sudo npm update -g @vue
sudo npm i -g @vue/cli-init
```

Answer (score 0):

before do you intall a vue project, uninstall the antivirus. To unblock  self signed certificate in certificate chain